# AWS Lambda unzip from S3 to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write an Lambda function that unzips zip files in one S3 directory and extract into another. I had this working in Python but nobody else in my group likes Python so I'm converting it to Node.js which I'm not very good at.

I'm trying to use the `unzipper` package and I'm able to get a list of files in the zip file using `unzipper.Open.S3`, but I can't figure out how to stream the files in the zip file into S3.

The meat of the code looks like

```
  const directory = await unzipper.Open.s3(s3,{Bucket: bucket, Key: zip_file});

  directory.files.forEach(file => {
    console.log("file name = " + file.path + ", type = " + file.type)
    const key = dir[0] + "/output/" + file.path;
    const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key };
    const { writeStream, promise } = uploadStream(params)
    file.stream().pipe(writeStream);
    promise.then(() => {
      console.log('upload completed successfully');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('upload failed.', err.message);
    });
  });

const uploadStream = ({ Bucket, Key }) => {
  const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
  return {
    writeStream: pass,
    promise: s3.upload({ Bucket, Key, Body: pass }).promise()
  };
}
```

I get the console.log for each file, but neither of the logs in `promise.then` and `.catch` comes out and no new files appear in S3.

Comment: If someone's looking for a python solution, this gives a detailed code and explanation: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind, I found this code that works better:

```
exports.handler = async (event) =>      {
    const params = {
    Key: zip_directory + "/" + zip_file,
    Bucket: input_bucket
  };

  const zip = s3
      .getObject(params)
      .createReadStream()
      .pipe(unzipper.Parse({ forceStream: true }));

  const promises = [];

  let num = 0;

  for await (const e of zip) {
    const entry = e;

    const fileName = entry.path;
    const type = entry.type;
    if (type === 'File') {
      const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: output_bucket,
        Key: output_directory + fileName,
        Body: entry,
      };

      promises.push(s3.upload(uploadParams).promise());
      num++;
    } else {
      entry.autodrain();
    }
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);

};
```

Comment: Hi. I would like to ask how did you initialize your `zip_directory` and `zip_file` variable when it came from the Lambda event (assuming that it's the method you used to initialize those variables.) I am also using `unzipper` and I'm currently stock with the same problem

Comment: @monkeybanana The code I ended up using isn't exactly like this, but I got the input key from the `event.Records[0].s3` input event and the output bucket and directory from `process.env`